# What environment does xargs pass to grep?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I am trying to search for two strings in a file. This is the command that I am using

`grep -l -r ads2gas | xargs grep vp8`

For some reasdon the second grep is not working correctly. I am getting "no such file or directory" errors.

The image below shows a few things.

a) the files do exist in the directory, as shown by the output of ls
b) running the xargs command with the -p argument shows the command before execution. It looks fine.
c) errors :-/
d) copy pasting the command provided by the -p argument actually works!?

[image]

The only thing that makes sense to me is that the second grep command isn't running in the current directory. Is that possible?

Can you either help me fix this command, or provide me with a better way t orecursively  search for two words inside files.

Thank you :)

Comment: I think you have grep setup to always colourize output (perhaps by an alias, or worse, by environment variables), and the colour codes are driving the second grep nuts. Try `grep --color=none ads2gas | xargs -p grep vp8`

Comment: Wow. I'm floored. I NEVER would have even been remotely close to finding that.
You're right. Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @muru I do have export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always' set. Why is this worse?  Although, yes, it was a problem here, it's usually not. Is there something that I should know? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have `grep` setup to always colourize output (perhaps by an alias, or worse, by environment variables), and the colour codes are driving the second `grep` nuts. Try:

```
grep --color=none ads2gas | xargs -p grep vp8
```

Setting `GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` is worse compared to aliases because aliases don't (usually) affect scripts, whereas this also affects scripts. I learned that [the hard way](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179156).

Comment: I actually figured out the "why it's worse" before you answered. I also found out the hard way ;)

Comment: @MikeWallaceDev you might want to change the alias to `color=auto` which is clever enough to detect when it's being piped and not print color for those cases.